# In javascript is there any easier way of mapping inbound rss tags to output rss tags?

Tags: javascript, xml, rss

I've been going round and round with this Javascript problem for four days and have finally managed to get it working. But I feel sure there must be a much better solution, one involving fewer 'translations', something that puts less strain on the browser.

I feel I should be able to read the xml of the feed, do a little re-mapping of tags in the inbound feed into tags in the outbound one. Can I? Do I have to stick with the solution I've got working:

In a nutshull, I'm taking via an http request an RSS feed that has some media tags. It 'arrives' as the xml of a dom structure that replicates the feed. I then have to reconstruct the feed items (with a little remapping) from that dom so they can be returned to the calling routine (via a global variable).

I've looked into all sorts of potential alternatives: jQuery.get, json and others but all examples I could find online seem to ignore the media items in the inbound feed - at least I couldn't find them when trying to read the feed.

This is an entry in the rss feed being used as the source:

```
<item>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">https://www.zazzle.com/create_your_own_photostamp_by_stamps_com-172639479866885637?rf=238582202591969585&amp;tc=_041218</guid>
    <pubDate>Mon, 19 Nov 2018 23:49:28 GMT</pubDate>
    <title>
        <![CDATA[Create Your Own PhotoStamp by Stamps.com]]>
    </title>
    <link>https://www.zazzle.com/create_your_own_photostamp_by_stamps_com-172639479866885637?rf=238582202591969585&amp;tc=_041218&amp;pm=</link>
    <author>
        <name>zazzle_templates</name>
    </author>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </description>
    <price>$myItem->price</price>
    <media:title>
        <![CDATA[Create Your Own PhotoStamp by Stamps.com]]>
    </media:title>
    <media:description>
        <![CDATA[Upload your own photo or design to create your set of custom photo postage stamps by Stamps.com!]]>
    </media:description>
    <media:price>$22.95</media:price>
    <media:thumbnail url="https://rlv.zcache.com/create_your_own_photostamp_by_stamps_com-r0453bb627c114b9da57442d3dd284e6a_byxt0_8byvr_152.jpg" />
    <media:content url="https://rlv.zcache.com/create_your_own_photostamp_by_stamps_com-r0453bb627c114b9da57442d3dd284e6a_byxt0_8byvr_500.jpg" />
    <media:keywords>
        <![CDATA[create your own, upload your own, template, postage stamp, mailing stamp, wedding, save the date, anniversary, birthday, occasion]]>
    </media:keywords>
    <media:rating scheme="urn:mpaa">g</media:rating>
</item>
```

This is the code I'm using (no, I'm not a coder. I mostly code by recognising patterns in examples and understanding equivalence of one thing with another)

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $.fn.rssfeed = function (url, options, fn) {
        return this.each(function (i, e) {
            if (!$(e).hasClass('rssFeed')) { $(e).addClass('rssFeed'); }
            if (url === null) { return false; }
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        process(this);
        if ($.isFunction(fn)) { fn.call(this, $(e)); }    }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url , true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        });
    };
    var process = function (xml) {
        var i, xmlDoc, table;
        xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        var myItemAsAnObject = [];
        feedLength = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item").length;
        console.log("feed length: " + feedLength);
        if (feedLength == 0) { return false; }
        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            myItemAsAnObject[i] = {
    pubDate: x[i].getElementsByTagName("pubDate")[0].firstChild.nodeValue,
    link: x[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].firstChild.nodeValue,
    keywords: x[i].getElementsByTagName("media:keywords")[0].childNodes[0].data,
    author: {name: x[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue},
    content: {url: x[i].getElementsByTagName("media:content")[0].attributes[0].nodeValue},
    description: [
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].data,
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("media:description")[0].childNodes[0].data
    ],
    guid: {isPermaLink: "false", content: x[i].getElementsByTagName("guid")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue},
    price: [
        "$myItem->price",
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("media:price")[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    ],
    thumbnail: {url: x[i].getElementsByTagName("media:thumbnail")[0].attributes[0].nodeValue},
    rating: {
        scheme: x[i].getElementsByTagName("media:rating")[0].attributes[0].nodeValue,
        content: x[i].getElementsByTagName("media:rating")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    },
    title: [
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.nodeValue,
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("media:title")[0].childNodes[0].data
    ]
            };
        }
        feedContent = myItemAsAnObject;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the parsing is actually pretty easy if you're only doing it in a browser. The following won't directly work in node but you could use js-dom (but honestly there's better xml parsers you should use in that case.)

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yQdjyo?editors=0010

```
const rss = `
<item>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">https://www.zazzle.com/create_your_own_photostamp_by_stamps_com-172639479866885637?rf=238582202591969585&amp;tc=_041218</guid>
    <pubDate>Mon, 19 Nov 2018 23:49:28 GMT</pubDate>
    <title>
        <![CDATA[Create Your Own PhotoStamp by Stamps.com]]>
    </title>
    <link>https://www.zazzle.com/create_your_own_photostamp_by_stamps_com-172639479866885637?rf=238582202591969585&amp;tc=_041218&amp;pm=</link>
    <author>
        <name>zazzle_templates</name>
    </author>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </description>
    <price>$myItem->price</price>
    <media:title>
        <![CDATA[Create Your Own PhotoStamp by Stamps.com]]>
    </media:title>
    <media:description>
        <![CDATA[Upload your own photo or design to create your set of custom photo postage stamps by Stamps.com!]]>
    </media:description>
    <media:price>$22.95</media:price>
    <media:thumbnail url="https://rlv.zcache.com/create_your_own_photostamp_by_stamps_com-r0453bb627c114b9da57442d3dd284e6a_byxt0_8byvr_152.jpg" />
    <media:content url="https://rlv.zcache.com/create_your_own_photostamp_by_stamps_com-r0453bb627c114b9da57442d3dd284e6a_byxt0_8byvr_500.jpg" />
    <media:keywords>
        <![CDATA[create your own, upload your own, template, postage stamp, mailing stamp, wedding, save the date, anniversary, birthday, occasion]]>
    </media:keywords>
    <media:rating scheme="urn:mpaa">g</media:rating>
</item>
`;

const doc = document.createDocumentFragment();
const root = document.createElement('div');
root.innerHTML = rss;

doc.appendChild(root);

// const getValue = (selector) => root.querySelectorAll(selector).innerHTML;

// const obj = {
//   pubDate: getValue('pubDate'),
//   link: getValue('link'),
//   keywords: getValue('media:keywords'),
//   author: {name: ''},
//   content: {url: ''},
//   description: [

//   ],
//   guid: '',
//   thumbnail: '',
//   rating: {
//     scheme: '',
//     content: ''
//   },
//   title: [

//   ]
// };

// console.log(obj);
```

This converts the xml string into a document fragment, and you can then run queries against it. `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` work fine as long as the xml nodes don't contain `:`. For example, `<media:price>` isn't parseable by querySelector.

This should at least make part of your code simpler.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I'm not sure why you've commented out the last half? You mention about the issue of `:` yet show media:keywords in the commented-out part. Am I missing something? Being able to 'get hold of' the media tags and their values is vital to the required parsing.

Comment: The commented portion was just an example of one way to get some kinds of values. But you should still be able to use more specific methods like `getElementsByTagName` like already are. The main part of my answer was just providing an easier native way of parsing the rss stream.